# Hexadecimal value equal to negative value

Tags: c, int, hex, signed

What 16-bit hexadecimal signed int value works with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    int i;
    if (scanf("%x", &i) != 1) break;
    printf("%d %s -%d\n", i, (i == -i) ? "==" : "!=", i); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There must be some value with which this returns "==", other than "0".

Comment: Why must there? And what does hex to do with this?

Comment: It's an excerpt from an assignment but the question is fairly simple. The hexadecimal is just the representation for the binary bits.

Comment: You're not using hexadecimal anywhere here - it's not relevant, unless there's a part of the assignment we're not seeing. Integers have no inherent (decimal, hexadecimal, binary) representation, until and unless you write them out to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8000` (hex) would be the answer (on a 16-bit machine).

It's because when you negate `8000` in 2's complement, you take the complement plus 1, so that's `7FFF + 1` or back to `8000`. In decimal representation, the number is, `-32768`.

In the case of the given code, this would be true *if* an `int` is 16 bits for the given compiler and processor. Otherwise, `i` would need to be declared as `short int` or just `short`.

Comment: Suggest `0x8000` is `-32768` and not `-65536`.

Comment: @chux hah yep good catch, thanks. Rule in computers: one's always off by a factor of 2. ;)

Comment: [Within a factor of 2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close_enough_for_government_work) is good enough sometimes.